# How can someone stop horizontal scrolling of Tab Component of NativeBase

Tags: react-native, tabs, native-base

RN: I am using tab component of native base. I tab bar component I want to stop scrolling horizontally because I am planning to have some horizontally scroll able view in first tab of this tab bar component. I just want tabs not to change when user drag right or left until he touches the icon itself.I am unable to find such a prop for it with the help of which I can stop that.  Hope you understand.  Here it is, I want to stop this.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
    render() {

return (
  <Container>


    <Tabs renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab  style={{ backgroundColor: '#4169E1' }} />} >
      <Tab
        heading={<TabHeading style={{ backgroundColor: '#4169E1' }}>
          <Icon name="home" style={{ color: 'white' }} />
        </TabHeading>}>

        <Text> This is Home </Text>


      </Tab>
      <Tab
        heading={<TabHeading style={{ backgroundColor: '#4169E1' }} >
          <Icon name="ios-search" style={{ color: 'white' }} />
        </TabHeading>}>
        <Text> This is Search </Text>

      </Tab>

      <Tab
        heading={<TabHeading style={{ backgroundColor: '#4169E1' }} >

          <SimpleLineIcons name='user' color='white' size={25} style={{ marginLeft: 20 }} />
        </TabHeading>}>

        <Text> THis is User </Text>


      </Tab>

      <Tab
        heading={<TabHeading style={{ backgroundColor: '#4169E1' }} >
          <Icon name="help" style={{ color: 'white' }} />
        </TabHeading>}>
        <Texy> </Text>
      </Tab>

      <Tab
        heading={<TabHeading style={{ backgroundColor: '#4169E1' }} >
          <Icon name="cog" style={{ color: 'white' }} />
        </TabHeading>}>
        <Settings />
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
  </Container>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

`<Tabs locked />`